# Trouble reading HTML table saved with gtsave

Tags: r, shiny, gt

I saved a table created by `gt` in HTML using `gtsave`.
I'm having trouble loading and displaying this small HTML table in Shiny

The HTML table is at: https://filedropper.com/d/s/CyvqjLggB4Q0IkJ60BQsZkIwy3BVPm

The error I get is:

`Warning: Error in FUN: argument is not a character vector`

R Script

```
library("shiny")
library("tidyverse")

# Get HTML table from here (11KB) https://filedropper.com/d/s/CyvqjLggB4Q0IkJ60BQsZkIwy3BVPm
tbl <- read_html(x = "<path to 001_ins_tbl.html>")


ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput(outputId = "ins_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ins_table <- renderUI({
    HTML(tbl)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `HTML(as.character(tbl))`

Comment: Just tried. No error. But no table either. Nothing.

Comment: Have you tried with a much smaller file? Generally questions should be self-sufficient and should not store data on remote sites since that's potentially dangerous. Are you trying to include an entire HTML page inside another HTML page? You cannot nest an `<html>` tag inside another `<html>` tag. Most browsers won't allow that. You need to make sure the resulting page is a valid HTML page. What is the code you used when you ran `gtsave`? The `gtsave` function does not appear to product HTML fragments. It only seems to create entire pages.

Comment: Understood. I did gtsave(data = x, filename =y). The file gtsave creates looks like a complete HTML page to me. So that's bad. At first, I tried saving the gt table as an R data file (.Rda). That sort of worked. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71775681/gt-table-works-in-rstudio-fails-on-srv-shiny-server

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It appears that you can save an HTML fragment with gt. See: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/gt/html/as_raw_html.html

Comment: Is this question solved?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was to use convert the HTML page to an HTML fragment using
`as_raw_html()`. In my case, this introduced an unwanted extra blank line in each cell which was removed by removing the <p> and </p> tags.

```
perk_html_tbl <- perk_html_tbl |>
      as_raw_html() |> 
      {function(x){gsub("<p>", "", x=x)}}() |> 
      {function(x){gsub("</p>", "", x=x)}}()
```